# How to read/calculte data using loop in python?

Tags: python, database, for-loop, read-data

I am the new for python. I try to process data (**g** in following) using difference method, that subtracts one array from others. I have the following codes. The difference between code 1 and code 2 is: **code 1 preallocates a space for list**, and in the loop  replace every value. **Code 2 only defines an empty list at first, and appends data to defined list in loop**. The results are the same. However, I'm not familiar with python and do not know which is good. Could  someone give me an advice? or a more developed modification about this code?

BR
XJ

```
#Same part:
g = range(1,12)
width  = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
length = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
width  = set(width)
length = set(width)
nr_w = len(width)
nr_l = len(length)
#different parts:
# %%
#Code 1:
i = 0
g_new_1 = [0]*nr_w*(nr_l-1) # preallocating
for i_w in range(nr_w):
    for i_l in range(nr_l):
        if i_l != 0:
            g_new_1[i] = g[i_w*nr_l+i_l] - g[i_w*nr_w]
            i=i+1
# %%
#Code 2:
g_new_2 = []
for i_w in range(nr_w):
    for i_l in range(nr_l):
        if i_l != 0:
            g_new_2.append( g[i_w*nr_l+i_l] - g[i_w*nr_w] )

print(g_new_1 == g_new_2)
```

Comment: It doesn't need to convert your lists to set in the same part. Code 2 is better.

Comment: Right now, the question is a bit unclear. What do you mean with subtraction? Is the result an array too, or do you subtract all pairs? Do you really mean the vector `g`? Then what are `width` and `height`?

Comment: @Heyran.rs I need to know the length of not repeated  data, so, in my case, this convert is necessary. Thx

Comment: @PhilippF I have simplified my case, but it is still a little unclear, sorry for that. In my case, every element with a **width** and a **length** has a data **g**. I want to subtract data **g** with minimal **length** from elements with other(larger) lengths for elements with same widths. I do not know what do you mean result is an array?